# How to catch errors such as ios 401, 403, etc. as an issue from the Sentry

Tags: ios, swift, sentry

I applied sentry in the **iOS** app, but if the app turns off abnormally, it will be caught in the sentry issue.
But I can't catch errors like `401` and `403`.

How can I set it to get status abnormal values?

my sentry init is below

```
SentrySDK.start { options in
    options.dsn = *dsn value
    options.debug = true 
    options.tracesSampleRate = 1.0
    options.diagnosticLevel = SentryLevel.debug
    options.enableCoreDataTracking = true
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you track theses error yourself? I'm not sure it's swizzling to get all theses errors by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sentry recently released a capturing [HTTP client errors automatically](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/apple/configuration/http-client-errors/) for the Cocoa SDK. Only HTTP client errors with a response code between 500 and 599 are default captured as error events, but you can change this behavior with `failedRequestStatusCodes`:

```
SentrySDK.start { options in
    // ...
    options.enableCaptureFailedRequests = true
    let httpStatusCodeRange = HttpStatusCodeRange(min: 400, max: 599)
    options.failedRequestStatusCodes = [ httpStatusCodeRange ]
}
```